# GNOME: cannot get rid of windows appearing on all workspaces, but only for external monitor

Tags: window, visibility, gnome

I have connected an external monitor to my laptop.

I now have strange behavior:

```
If an application window is on the primary screen, then it will only be shown on one desktop.
If a window is on the external monitor, then it will be shown on ALL desktops, which normally doesn't make sense. It is as if the "pinned" feature is set, or something like "show on all workspaces", but only if the window is placed on the external monitor.
Specifically, these are e.g. windows of Terminal, Firefox, Libreoffice etc.

I haven't found a place to configure that away. If you right-click on the top bar of the window (context menu), there are items "minimize", "maximize", move, resize, always on top (is off), move to the right screen, close.
```

Exciting: I just found that on the primary screen the windows have the additional item "always on visible work surface" in the menu, but the item is no longer available on the external screen.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer: start "gnome-tweaks" and search for "workspace" (= "Arbeitsflächen" in German), there is an option "workspace only on the primary screen" OR "workspace has several screens" (translated from German). Choose the second option!